# Too many pythons on my Mac, and pip install is not install package into the right python package folder

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I want to use virtualenv on my Mac, and I installed it with pip:

```
pip install virtualenv

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for virtualenv, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv ... done
Successfully installed virtualenv
```

**Apparently, virtualenv is not installed into the correct Python packages folder. And here is the error:**

```
virtualenv -p python3 --system-site-packages py3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 655, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'virtualenv==15.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Then I figured I have too many Pythons on my Mac:

```
sudo find / -type d -name "*site-packages*"

find: /dev/fd/user: No such file or directory
find: /dev/fd/user: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/testsuite/test_apps/lib/python2.5/site-packages
/opt/X11/lib/python2.6/site-packages
/private/var/folders/17/y6xv651n50j6gplk57ythm8m0000gn/T/pip-Nexe_V-uninstall/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/private/var/folders/17/y6xv651n50j6gplk57ythm8m0000gn/T/pip-PpXcxM-uninstall/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/private/var/folders/17/y6xv651n50j6gplk57ythm8m0000gn/T/pip-ROUjc9-uninstall/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/Users/user/Downloads/virtualenv-15.0.3/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/user/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/factory-reset-backup/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Users/user/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/factory-reset-backup/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Users/user/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Users/user/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Users/user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
/Users/user/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages
/Users/user/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.11.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.11.1/libexec/nose/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.12.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.12.1/libexec/nose/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.12.1/libexec/nose/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/git/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

My current python is pointed to `/usr/local/bin/python`, and my pip is pointed to `/usr/local/bin/pip`.  And this what's inside of the default pip:

```
cat /usr/local/bin/pip

#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==9.0.1','console_scripts','pip'
__requires__ = 'pip==9.0.1'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
    )
```

And my virtualenv executable is something like this:

```
cat /usr/local/bin/virtualenv

#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'virtualenv==15.1.0','console_scripts','virtualenv'
__requires__ = 'virtualenv==15.1.0'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('virtualenv==15.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
    )
```

**How to clean my python installation and point pip and virtualenv installation to the current python package folder?**

BTW, without pass pip install-option argument, pip install is not installing packages to the current default python package folder.

```
pip install --install-option="--install-purelib=/python/packages" virtualenv
```

**Even after use pip3, something is still weird with my python:**

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for virtualenv, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv ... done
Successfully installed virtualenv



virtualenv -p python3 --system-site-packages py3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 655, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'virtualenv==15.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application




pip3 install --install-option="--install-purelib=/python/packages" virtualenv
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for virtualenv, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/17/y6xv651n50j6gplk57ythm8m0000gn/T/pip-build-mvjkq8ur/virtualenv/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/17/y6xv651n50j6gplk57ythm8m0000gn/T/pip-y9p6_ro7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-purelib=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages --install-purelib=/python/packages:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    copying virtualenv.py -> build/lib
    creating build/lib/virtualenv_support
    copying virtualenv_support/__init__.py -> build/lib/virtualenv_support
    copying virtualenv_support/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl -> build/lib/virtualenv_support
    copying virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl -> build/lib/virtualenv_support
    copying virtualenv_support/setuptools-28.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl -> build/lib/virtualenv_support
    copying virtualenv_support/wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl -> build/lib/virtualenv_support
    running install_lib
    byte-compiling /python/packages/virtualenv.py to virtualenv.cpython-36.pyc
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/python/packages/__pycache__'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/17/y6xv651n50j6gplk57ythm8m0000gn/T/pip-build-mvjkq8ur/virtualenv/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/17/y6xv651n50j6gplk57ythm8m0000gn/T/pip-y9p6_ro7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-purelib=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages --install-purelib=/python/packages" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/17/y6xv651n50j6gplk57ythm8m0000gn/T/pip-build-mvjkq8ur/virtualenv/



sudo pip3 install --install-option="--install-purelib=/python/packages" virtualenv
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
The directory '/Users/yong/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/yong/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz (1.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.9MB 824kB/s
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv ... done
Successfully installed virtualenv



virtualenv -p python3 --system-site-packages py3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 655, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'virtualenv==15.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application



ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
__pycache__                      pip                              pkg_resources                    setuptools-32.2.0-py3.6.egg-info wheel
easy_install.py                  pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg-info         setuptools                       sitecustomize.py                 wheel-0.29.0-py3.6.egg-info



ls /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Flask_MongoRest-0.1.1-py2.7.egg      colorclass-2.2.0-py2.7.egg-info      idna                                 pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.7.egg-info       terminaltables-3.1.0-py2.7.egg-info
Flask_Views-0.2.1-py2.7.egg          colorclass-2.2.0-py3.6.egg-info      idna-2.5-py2.7.egg-info              pyparsing-2.2.0-py3.6.egg-info       terminaltables-3.1.0-py3.6.egg-info
Flask_WTF-0.9.5-py2.7.egg            coverage-3.7.1-py2.7.egg             idna-2.5-py3.6.egg-info              pyparsing.py                         textblob
IPython                              dateutil                             jinja2                               pyparsing.pyc                        twisted
Pygments-1.6-py2.7.egg               django                               lxml                                 python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.7.egg-info urllib3
WTForms-1.0.5-py2.7.egg              docopt-0.6.2-py2.7.egg-info          mongoengine                          queuelib                             urllib3-1.21.1-py2.7.egg-info
__pycache__                          docopt-0.6.2-py3.6.egg-info          mysql-0.0.1-py2.7.egg-info           requests                             urllib3-1.21.1-py3.6.egg-info
awscli-1.9.12-py2.7.egg              docopt.py                            nameparser                           requests-2.17.3-py2.7.egg-info       virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg-info
boto                                 docopt.pyc                           nltk                                 requests-2.17.3-py3.6.egg-info       virtualenv-15.1.0-py3.6.egg-info
bs4                                  docutils                             nose                                 scrapy                               virtualenv.py
cerberus                             eve                                  nose-1.3.1-py2.7.egg                 simplejson                           virtualenv.pyc
certifi                              events                               packaging                            six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg-info            virtualenv_support
certifi-2017.4.17-py2.7.egg-info     flask                                packaging-16.8-py2.7.egg-info        six-1.10.0-py3.6.egg-info            werkzeug
certifi-2017.4.17-py3.6.egg-info     flask_cuddlyrest                     packaging-16.8-py3.6.egg-info        six.py                               wtforms
chardet                              flask_mongoengine                    pandas                               six.pyc                              zmq
chardet-3.0.3-py2.7.egg-info         flask_mongoengine-0.7.0-py2.7.egg    pattern                              sklearn
chardet-3.0.3-py3.6.egg-info         flask_restful                        pip_upgrader                         sphinx
cleancat-0.3-py2.7.egg               flask_views                          pip_upgrader-1.4.0-py2.7.egg-info    tablib
colorclass                           flask_wtf                            pip_upgrader-1.4.0-py3.6.egg-info    terminaltables
```

I had to copy the files to python 3.6 to make it work.

```
cp -R /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py3.6.egg-info /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
cp -R /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.pyc /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
cp -R /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

Comment: why not use absolute path to pip or simply cd into the folder that has the pip or python you want to use?

Comment: When installing pip for a particular python version, it always comes with a symlink. For example, after installing pip for python3.6, you can then refer to that pip version as `pip3.6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are installing your package on python2.7 but then checking for its availability on python3!!

When you install multiple versions of python, usually it will also come with it's own version of pip.
e.g. python3 will also have pip3 installed.
Look for it in directories like below so:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3.4

On my machine, I also have a pip3 which points to the latest version of python3 (in my case python3.4) installed on my machine.

Then you simply do:

```
pip3 install <yourpackage>
```

Comment: ```
Failed to import the site module
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 2.x but you are running Python 3.x!
     PYTHONPATH is currently: ":/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
     You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.
```
How to keep 2.7 as default, and still be able to use 3.x?

Comment: Whatever python program you're trying to run, make sure it's calling the right version of python. e.g. change the "shbang" line to point to your python3 binary:
`#!/usr/local/bin/python3` 
(this is an example, use the correct path for python3 on your system).  

Alternatively, you can invoke the program like so:
`python3 <myprogram>`

Comment: Something weird is going on, I did what you said and the package is still in python2.7 package folder. So, eventually, I copied the files to my python 3.6 package folder and it worked. `cp -R /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py3.6.egg-info /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
cp -R /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.pyc /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
cp -R /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
`